# Insufficent space for shared memory file when i try the run command on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

when i run the command "mvn clean package spring-boot:run" i get this error:

```
OpenJdk 64-Bit Server VM warning: Insufficent space for shared memory file: 3362281 Try using the -Djava.io.tmpdir= option to select an alternate temp location.
```

I have used this command in the past week a lot of time and it always worked.

This is the output of the Df -h command:

```
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                      1,6G  1,9M  1,6G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root   19G   18G     0 100% /
tmpfs                      7,9G   44M  7,8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                      5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda2                  512M  5,3M  507M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs                      1,6G  2,4M  1,6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

I understand it's a problem of memory but i'm not sure what folder i should delete/modify. In this project there a lot of dependency so i don't want to delete some folder that i need to run the project. Can you help me?

Comment: Your disk is full; nothing (directly) to do with eclipse

Comment: can i safely delete the mapper directory in dev/mapper? Inside mapper there are 3 files.

Comment: No. You generally do not remove or touch files under `/dev/`.

Comment: Does rebooting help?

Comment: Simply disk is full. You have to check why the disk is full ...which location you are using (for example /home) and why so much stuff is stored there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your disk is full; nothing (directly) to do with eclipse or Java.

I note that your main disk is 19G, which is small by today's standards; I assume this is not your laptop or desktop, but rather a machine in the cloud or a virtual machine (VM).

Depending on your situation, you have two general options:

- Reduce the amount of space you use, by deleting or moving files that you do not need — not in the system area, but in your own directories.

  You can also uninstall applications you don't need, using the package manager; however, on a small machine like this, I imagine you haven't installed anything superfluous.
- Increase the amount of space available; if it's a machine in the cloud or a virtual machine, you can do this by changing the configuration. The exact procedure depends on which cloud or which virtual machine technology.

  If it's in the cloud, increasing the disk size will increase the cost; you will need to check whether the resulting amount is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Free some space at /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root and it will work. Seems that your FS is full.

Comment: vgubuntu-root is not a directory but a sort of file. How can i free some space?

Comment: That's a representation of the main disk; all your ordinary files. You'll either need to have a look at what you're storing and either delete or move files that you no longer need; or, you'll need to increase the disk size (particularly if it's a virtual machine or in the cloud, where that can be done easily).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm late. Now I will do my best to help you.

Your VM's disk space is full, that means 100% used. What I say is `/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root`, you can see that's Use% is `100%`.

You need to expand your VM's disk space size and your VM's space size.

As I see from your command `Df -h` outputting, your VM's disk space size is about `19.5 GB`(Size_vm==Size_dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root+Size_/dev/sda2), your VM is `Ubuntu`, and you build your VM `Ubuntu` via `vg` on your host machine.

Your host machine should give `40 GB` or even `60GB` for your VM's space size. I recommend you more than `60 GB`. Because if the used percent of a disk size is up to `80`, that means `80%` used disk's size, that disk is in dangerous status. What's more, 50% used disk can use for many years and the faster allocated based on the principles of microcomputers. If you set `40 GB`, now your VM disk's used percent is up to `49%`; and if you set `60 GB`, now your VM disk's used percent is up to `32%`; also, if you set `100GB`, now your VM disk's used percent is up to `20%`. And so on.

Notices: That I said your VM's space size is virtual memory, your VM data's size is the really physical memory size of your VM. Also, your setting VM's disk space size is the maximum size of your VM's physical memory, is the virtual memory, but if your VM disk is `100%` used, your VM disk's size become the physical memory. There are three types of space size. So no matter how you set your VM's space size or your VM's disk space size. What I said XXX memory is storage.

```
item                 virtual memory/storage  physical memory/storage           maximum size

Host machine's space         Yes                      No                     >=Size_hm_disk
(Size_hm_space)

Host machine's Disk          No                       Yes                    ==Size_hm_disk
(Size_hm_disk)

VM's space                   Yes                      No                     <=Size_hm_disk
(Size_vm_space)

VM's Disk space              Yes             No, but 100% used becomes      <=Size_vm_space
(Size_vm_disk_space)

VM's Data space              No                       Yes              <=Size_vm_disk_space
(Size_vm_data)
```

Solution:

1.Using `vg` give VM space `60 GB`:

I think your VM's bridge `vg` is just like `VirtualBox`, so please just use `vg` to give your VM's space `60GB`. This place, I just use `60 GB` for an example.

Please use `sudo cfdisk` to check your VM's disk on your VM terminal, I guess your output just liking below:

```
Device         Boot    Start      End    Sectors      Size    Id Type           Mounted
/dev/mapper/.   *      512M      19.5G 40162880     19G       83 Linux          /
/dev/sda2              19.5G      20G   1006800     512M      c W95 FAT32(LBA)  /boot/efi
```

2.Expand VM's disk space:

First, you should use `fdisk` or `cfdisk` or `parted` to move your second partition `/dev/sda2` which mounted in `/boot/efi` to the end cylinder of your VM's disk.

Second, Using `cfdisk` to resize or extend or enlarge your first partition `/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root`, may be the default size of resized `/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root` operated by `cfdisk`is `59.5 GB`;

Third, do not forget set all the file types of partition `/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root` into ext4 via `sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root`.

Fourth, restart or reboot your virtual machine, and have fun!

Others, DO NOT stupidly delete partition `/dev/sda2` or any files in partiton `/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root` just liking me! :)

OVER!